# Use a pre-constructed string as bson.M for mgo query in go

Tags: go, marshalling, bson, mgo, gorilla

The larger goal here is to have an update query in go set only those fields that are sent to it in the request.

For e.g., I have a document to update where I am allowing the user to update a variable number of fields by simply specifying them in the request like so -

```
{
"field1": valueOfField1,
"field2": valueOfField2,
"field3": valueOfField3,
...
}
```

The problem here is that when I decode this input using `json.Decode` to a custom struct type which has most fields optional, the values which do not exist in the input are left `nil`.

My struct looks like this -

```
type Fields struct {
    Field1       string      `bson:"field1" json:"field1,omitempty"`
    Field2       string      `bson:"field2" json:"field2"`
    Field3       time.Time   `bson:"field3,omitempty" json:"field3,omitempty"`
    Field4       bool        `bson:"field4,omitempty" json:"field4,omitempty"`
...
}
```

Now in my update query, I say,

```
bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"field1": body.Field1, "field2": body.Field2, "field3": body.Field3, "field4": body.Field4, ...}}
```

The problem is that if one of these fields does not exist in the input, it still over-writes existing values in the database and makes it null.

To avoid this, I would ideally want that this `{"field1": body.Field1, "field2": body.Field2, "field3": body.Field3, "field4": body.Field4, ...}` part is dynamically constructed depending on the fields coming in.

To do that, I did a `json.Marshal` of the input, like so -

```
finalbody, err := json.Marshal(body)
```

And then I am trying to use this inside the $set field as -

```
bson.M{"$set": string(finalbody)}
```

Of course this gives me an error saying - "Modifiers operate on fields but we found a string instead".
The string is perfectly just like the bson.M would've been except that it is not a bson.M i.e. `{"field1": valueOfField1, "field2": valueOfField2, "field3": valueOfField1, ...}`

Where am I going wrong?
[... represents 'and so on']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by Unmarshalling finalbody into a map[string]interface{} and then using that as the update map.

So,

```
finalbody, err := json.Marshal(body)
var finalbodymap map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(finalbody, &finalbodymap)
```

Of course, you need to add some error handling so the final code looks like this -

```
finalbody, err := json.Marshal(body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
var finalbodymap map[string]interface{}
    if err = json.Unmarshal(finalbody, &finalbodymap); err != nil{
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

And then in the update query, I can simply write -

```
bson.M{"$set": finalbodymap}
```

One issue here though was that while Marshalling, it would set any time.Time type values to nil i.e. "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z". I suspect such behavior could be observed with certain other types as well.

Comment: Hey buddy, You did a great job!